# Why is browser raising a CORS exception if the origin are the same?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

Ok, so this is weird.

I already know what on origin is (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin), how to correctly use the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header, and so on, but this is something never view before.

I have a "father" window.
This window is opening a "child" window through the window.open(url) method.
the url provided is the same url of the father window:

```
var childWindow = window.open(window.location.href);
```

When the father window try to access to a property of the childWindow, it obtains the cross-origin error:

```
childWindow.data;
> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin XXXXXXXXXXXXX from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Interesting thing is: in the browser developer console of "father" window, typing

```
window.location.origin;
```

prints the origin (something like http://a.b.c)

and in the browser developer console of "child" window, typing

```
window.location.origin;
```

prints **esactly the same origin** (something like http://a.b.c)

Notes: there are no iframes involved here. The window.location.href URL is responding with 200 OK (not 302 or other things) and a simple page html with some css and scripts.

Note #2: the two instructions are executed sequentially. In the middle there are no other codes.

Note #3: obviously XXXXXXXXXXX is not the real origin, I omitted it for privacy concerns. But it is something like http://a.b.c (implicit port 80)

Note #4: is not relevant here because it should also work without it, but the window.location.href URL is responding with the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": *

Any thought?

Comment: You didn't post the entire complete URLs, but note that the origin includes the protocol ("http" or "https"), the host name (your "a.b.c"), *and* the port. If one URL has no port number and the other URL has an explicit ":80", then they do not match.

Comment: This is not correct, if one origin has no port and the other has port 80, the origin are the same (see the MDN article on that):

These are same origin because a server delivers HTTP content through port 80 by default:
- http://Example.com:80
- http://example.com

However, this is not my case.
as written, if I execute

window.location.origin in the father window and in the child window, I obtain exactly the same origin

Comment: So you are on http and not like a local file. can you make a fake url using like `example.com` Does one actually have a port number?

Comment: @user1561017 that is not correct, except in Internet Explorer (which was/is a bug)

Comment: Yep, I'm on http and not a local file. I cannot post the real url, but is something like 

http://www.google.it

but is not google :)

Comment: @Pointy: have you read MDN reference? I posted the url on top of that.
It clearly states that
"Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), hostname (domain), and port of the URL used to access it. Two objects have the same origin only when the scheme, hostname, and port all match."

Then there are a sequence of example like the one I reported. I think MDN is not wrong...

Comment: Yes, I have. The thing is, the MDN article is incomplete. An *explicit* port, even if it's the default port, makes a URL distinct from one that does not have an explicit port.

Comment: @user1561017 Modern browsers treat `http://example.com` and `http://example.com:80` as different origin. Your "not correct" comment is not correct. When they say must match it means the "string" must match, not the underlying connection. So the strings `http://example.com` and `http://example.com:80` don't match. The first has **empty string** as "port", not "80"

Comment: That is very interesting, I never doubted of MDN. Still, I'm inclined to think that MDN is correct. However, this is another question and I will create another Stack Overflow post for that, for the sake of knowledge ;)
Back to my case, there is still no difference at all. The first origin is "http://a.b.c" and the second origin is "http://a.b.c". They are absolutely the same String, character for character... but still the browser is giving me the CORS error.